# How to get the URL from a internet radio station so I can stream it from VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, wireshark, url, sniffing, internet-radio

How do I could get the embedded URL from this internet radio? http://wp.1045radiolatina.com/escucha-en-vivo/

What I meaning by URL from where is the radio is streamed.

I have been trying to use URL snooper but no luck there.

Want to be able to play it from VLC then I need the correct URL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has been already been answered: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314897/how-to-get-direct-streaming-url-from-this-flash-online-streaming-radio-station

To answer your question, right click -> advanced open -> Network, then paste this URL:
http://15383.live.streamtheworld.com/XLTNFMAAC?streamtheworld_user=1&uuid=16926000%2D0000%2D0001%2DFD9D%2D7EE019381205&nobuf=1479265442950

The URL is found by right-clicking the browser page and choosing "Inspect Element." The Network tab will indicate the stream URLs.

Answer (score 2):

In my review of the guides above, none worked for me, but we all know how often the internet changes.
This example is based on iHeartRadio Smooth Jazz station

Using Apple's Safari Browser v15.2

1. Find your station at iHeart's web page, and start the stream press the play ▶️ button
2. Right Click on the page and select "Inspect Page" next follow the steps in the image attached.

[Marked up Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjMU6.png)

I'm using VLC player, so once you've copy the address go to VLC and open "File" and click on "Open Network".  Paste the URL and press play.

You may save this as a playlist for playing later. Note: I have no idea how long this address will be good for.   Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Edge:

1. Open the web radio station of your choice, and pause it
2. Right Click and choose Inspect
3. Choose the Network Header, and then usually the Fetch/XHR subcategory
4. Hit the play button or CtrlR and observe a growing line under Waterfall.
5. If not, try the "Media" category
6. Click the Name to the left, right click the "Request URL"
7. Select "Copy Value"
8. 7 Paste (CtrlV) this value into for example VLC Media Player
9. Voila!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxS7P.png)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: @help-info.de before commenting make sure it is relevant. I think GunnarNyb's answer is good!

Answer (score -2):

this nice s/w gives the solution urlgetter.com as all streams have different ways to inspect

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.